# Regex which detect text at the end of url

Tags: jquery, regex, typescript

The title may be not appropriate but that I am trying to do is to cut url in certain condition. I want to create an regex which will throw away '/' at the end of the link.

For example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I was able to archieve this with this `^(.*)\/`([example](https://regex101.com/r/egAQvX/1)) but now I needed a change, and I'm not sure how it supposed to look.

Basically, the change I need is to DON'T touch the '/' if it is main page:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/ stays http://stackoverflow.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ changes to ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

From my point of view it supposes to look if url are ended with text between two '/' and without any '.', but so far I am failing to make this condition.

How it potentially supposed to look?

**EDIT**

Some of the url may not contain http or https, so for me it is totally ok if  regex regex will work on a normal text to.

Comment: Try `^(?!http://stackoverflow\.com/$)(.*)/$`

Comment: I used this url only as an example.

Comment: Please specify the language using another tag when using this tag, as documented in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: My suggestion above uses the url as an example, too. The idea is working.

Comment: If you mean there can be any protocol followed by any host, you may try `/^(?![^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+\/$)(.*)\/$/`

Comment: Made and edit in a question. Marked it.

Comment: I am not really sure what you need now, because how can you identify it is a URL you need? Following your current logic, the pattern you may use is `/^(?!(?:[^:]+:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/$)(.*)\/$/`. Or maybe exclude whitespaces: ``/^(?!(?:[^\s:]+:\/\/)?[^\/\s]+\/$)(.*)\/$/``

Comment: I would use something easier here: check number of occurences of '/' in url: if 3 - leave string as it is, if more, strip the last one. So, maybe you could do it without regex?

Comment: Wiktor, you didn't read my edit :(.  It is very easy to do without regex, but sadly, because of some circumstances I needed one.

Comment: Олег, I *read* your edit. `(?:[^\s:]+:\/\/)?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `xxx://`

Comment: Then you could see that is't not a problem if regex don't care if there is a start of the link (url) or not. Basically for exampe, if ­`test.test/` stays as it is but `test.test/test/` becames `test.test/test` it is enough for me

Comment: [Yes, I could see and saw it](https://regex101.com/r/eSxqj7/1).

Answer (score 0):

If URL starts with http:// or https:// you can use following pattern.

```
(http[s]*://.*?/.*)/$
```

Answer (score 0):

This process can help:

```
^(http[s]?:\/\/[^\/]*)(.*)\/
```

**Required URL = Group 1. + Group 2.**

```
if Group 2 empty then
   1. It is main Url 
   2. Add "/" at the end
else 
   1. It is **not** main URL
   2. Keep it as it is
```

---

**[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/egAQvX/9)**

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to throw away the forward slash if it's just a trailing character and keep it if it denotes some kind of path in your website.

All that requires is checking whether the forward slash is the last character (I'm pretty sure that's the simplest way of going about it).

```
(?(?=\/$)(.+)\/)
```

This regex uses an if statement to check whether the forward slash is the last character, and in which case matches everything up until the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
(.*\.[a-z]+\/?(?:[\w]+(?:\/[\w]+)*)*)
```

The result will be stored in `Group1`, see example here https://regex101.com/r/egAQvX/6

Answer (score 0):

… Following your current logic, the pattern you may use is `/^(?!(?:[^:]+:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/$)(.*)\/$/`. Or maybe exclude whitespaces: `/^(?!(?:[^\s:]+:\/\/)?[^\/\s]+\/$)(.*)\/$/`
                    – Wiktor Stribiżew